# Function is not getting called in Controller through ajax

Tags: magento-1.7, controllers

What are the steps to be taken care while calling function through controller?
I have created button in `admin/system/configuration`. On button click , function is called.  But it is not calling controller function.

URL path is

```
Mage::getUrl('price/marketplaceprice/ringsbands14k'),
```

controller file is `MarketPlacepriceController.php`

Comment: if you added this in js then do that `url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('price/marketplaceprice/ringsbands14k');?>",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajax call Write Url like below

```
function update_14k_rings_bands() { 
    alert("14k rings");
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getAjaxCheckUrl() ?>', { 
        url: "url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplacereport/marketplacereport/check'); ?>", 
        method:'post', data: { product_id: 1, ggg : 'hhh' }, 
        onSuccess: function(result){ 
            if (result.responseText){ alert(result.responseText); } 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Change config.xml Below code

```
<admin>
  <!-- This Is For Admin Routers -->
  <routers>
    <adminhtml> 
      <args>
        <modules>
           <marketplacereport before="Mage_Adminhtml">Marketplace_Report_Adminhtml
           </marketplacereport>
        </modules>
      </args>
   </adminhtml>
 </routers>
</admin>
```

This will work for you .

Comment: yes, I have written same format only.

Comment: Can you give full code of that ajax call, and also check my updated answer

Comment: function update_14k_rings_bands() {
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getAjaxCheckUrl() ?>', {
   url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('price/marketPlaceprice/check');?>",
            method:'get',
   data: { 
    product_id: 1
   },
            onSuccess: function(result){
            if (result.responseText){
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Check My updated answer

Comment: I have checked your updated answer but still no effect

Comment: So what is exactly your prblem is can you describe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44515/discussion-between-jassi-and-murtuza).

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `marketPlaceprice` instead of `marketplaceprice`.  Uppercase `P`.

Comment: i  changed to P but no effect